# rcp ComboViewer valueChanged

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

How to trigger an event in comboviewer if value in combobox is changed?  not every selection, triggered (addSelectionChangedListener).  I just want to trigger an event, ONLY IF currently different value selected, not same.

For example:
combobox, value {1,2,3}.  I set to 1. When I open combobox, and click 1, it WILL NOT triggered the event.  But when I click 2 or 3, it will triggered the event.  Something like in html,  that only trigger the event, only the event changed.  I have tested with comboViewer.getCombo().addMofidyListener.  but the case is same with selectionChangedListener above (same value clicked in combobox will always trigger the event).

Thanks

Comment: modifyListener works correctly in your case. I tested under linux

Answer (score 2):

ComboViewer can't do this by itself.  Try writing a selection listener that remembers the old value.

```
abstract class CleverSelectionChangedListener implements ISelectionChangedListener {

    private Object _oldSelection;

    public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {
        Object newSelection = ((IStructuredSelection) event.getSelection()).getFirstElement();
        if (newSelection != _oldSelection) {
            selectionReallyChanged(event);
            _oldSelection = newSelection;
        }
    }
    public abstract void selectionReallyChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event);
}
```